# Linq2DB - Generate Data Model for a given schema only

Tags: linq2db

Trying to Linq2DB for the first time - I have DB with multiple different schemas. Only a selected schema needs to be ORMed. Currently, it is generating multiple classes, some of which are duplicates. I have same tables across schemas.

so, how do I filter out schemas that I don't want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out not needed schema in T4 template.
According to documentation https://linq2db.github.io/articles/T4.html

```cs
GetSchemaOptions.IncludedSchemas = new[] {"some_schema"};

// or by exclusion
GetSchemaOptions.ExcludedSchemas = new[] {"some_unwanted_schema"};

LoadMetadata(...);

GenerateModel();
```

Comment: I got "No best type found for implicitly-typed array" when I tried that. Should it be: GetSchemaOptions.IncludedSchemas = new []{ "some_schema" }; ?

Comment: Yes, my fault. Corrected.